# Trying to convert a message in its bits counterparts

Tags: c, char, bit-manipulation, cs50, function-definition

I have the code below which should convert an user message input to its bits counterpart.
For example "Hi!" should be converted to
01001000
01001001
00100001

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int printbulbs(int ascii_input);
int main(void)
{
    char *Mesaj = get_string("Message: ");
    int size = strlen(Mesaj);
    int *ascii_conversion = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for( int i =0; i < size; i++)
    {

        ascii_conversion[i] = (int)Mesaj[i];

    }

    for ( int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printbulbs(ascii_conversion[i]);
    }

    free(ascii_conversion);
}

int printb(int ascii_input)
{
    int bits = sizeof(int) * 8;
    char* bits_message = malloc(bits+ 1);
    bits_message[bits] ='\0';

    for (int i= bits-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        bits_message[i] = (ascii_input & 1) + '0';
        ascii_input >>= 1;

    }

    printf("%s\n", bits_message);
    free(bits_message);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code I get the below result:

> Message: Hi!
> 00000000000000000000000001001000
> 00000000000000000000000001101001
> 00000000000000000000000000100001

But the correct result should be:

> Message: Hi!
> 01001000
> 01001001
> 00100001

Comment: What is the point of the `ascii_conversion` array? Why are you passing `int`s around instead of `char`? `int bits = sizeof(int) * 8;` - what does this represent?

Comment: `int bits = sizeof(int) * 8;` is 32. If you want to print 8 bits then you should just print each char from the original string and not do all the unnecessary char->int conversion.

Comment: Ascii_conversion should take each character from the Mesaj[i] array and transfrom it into it's integer counterpart based on ASCII.
for example H is 73 in ASCII
I is 72 in ASCII and
! is 33 in ASCII
Then I want the application to transform the integer in 1 and 0's and print it.
The plan is later to take the message, hash it with a function and then relay the converted message.  Basically protecting the message

Once I have theConvers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then you have that the expression used as an initializer in this declaration

```
int bits = sizeof(int) * 8;
```

is equal to `32`.

Also to output bits there is no great sense to allocate dynamically an array as you are doing

```
int *ascii_conversion = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

//...

char* bits_message = malloc(bits+ 1);
```

Pay attention to that the code has a typo in the function name.

On the one hand, the function is called like

```
printbulbs(ascii_conversion[i]);
^^^^^^^^^^
```

But in its definition its name is different

```
int printb(int ascii_input)
    ^^^^^^^
```

Also the return type `int` does have a useful information. It would be better to declare it like `void`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio,h>
#include <limits.h>

void printbulbs( char c )
{
    char bits[CHAR_BIT];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
    {
        bits[CHAR_BIT - i - 1] = ( c & 1 ) + '0';
        c = ( unsigned char )c >> 1;
    }

    printf( "%.*s", CHAR_BIT, bits );
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *message = "Hi!";

    printf( "%s ", message );

    for ( const char *p = message; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if (p != message) putchar( ' ' );
        printbulbs( *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hi! 01001000 01101001 00100001
```

Comment: The reason I have allocated dynamically is because I am trying to practice memory allocation to do it right. Indeed it is not needed, I is just for me to practice it.
But thank you for your answer. The solution in the end was to do
Int bits = sizeof(int) * 2